# WebAppLocalServer is not defined (android device)

Tags: javascript, android, meteor, amazon-ec2

I'm deploying my app on an aws EC2 instance, it works great until I want to run it as an android app on my physical device.

I deployed my app on AWS with Arunoda's MUP.
- node version : 0.10.40
- meteor version : 1.2.1

I run it with `meteor run --settings settings-development.json android-device --mobile-server http://my.ip.is.here`

Then, I get the unfortunately famous errors concerning CORS on meteor.local. Therefore, I use `App.accessRule("*")` to avoid it.

But when I do that, I know get only one log : "Uncaught ReferenceError :WebAppLocalServer is not defined". That's the only log I can deal with now. And not a single post seems to exists here or on SO or anywhere else about it.

When I try to upgrade the app to the meteor 1.3 beta, I get CORS error again (on http://my.ip/_timesync), though I still use `App.accessRule("*")`.

There is, according to my searches, absolutely nothing, no related doc, about the WebAppLocalServer error I get. I'm soon to be done with all that CORS and android device stuff -_-'

Here are the `--verbose` :

```
 I20160316-17:34:57.617(1) (android:file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js:173) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Loading from url: http://meteor.local
I20160316-17:34:57.702(1) (android:http://meteor.local/753cf1d0f224d17b3e38ba586d04c9dc3aee4c15.js:103) Uncaught ReferenceError: WebAppLocalServer is not defined
I20160316-17:34:57.703(1)? I/chromium(27295): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(130)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I20160316-17:34:57.703(1) (android:file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js:173) METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Loading from url: http://meteor.local
I20160316-17:35:00.690(1) (android:http://meteor.local/753cf1d0f224d17b3e38ba586d04c9dc3aee4c15.js:103) Uncaught ReferenceError: WebAppLocalServer is not defined
```

What should I do ? I'm blocking on this problem for a week now, and I found nothing helpfull :S

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Finally, for I don't know what reason, that bugged disapeared after in totally uninstalled / reinstalled the app from my phone, like if rolling back from 1.3 beta had left some untouched code is the phone app.........